# Rundeck dead? - Docker setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rundeck, pagerduty

I've been looking at trying out rundeck but what I've found is that the project is kind of abandoned?
The github material is all abandoned and deprecated and there is no comprehensive guides for rundeck anywhere to be found.
Does anyone know what happened to this project? Is it only enterprise paying customer support these days?

I couldn't even get by the login screen. You get CSP login error. One way to pass it would be to disable this security check but if you use docker compose, you can not use volume mounts because whenever you run the container, rundeck, for some reason, rewrites the files.
If you do it like

```
volumes:

   - data:/home/rundeck/server/data:ro
```

You will get error and container will crash, saying can not write to the file. But if you set it as normal with RW permissions, your files will be overwritten inside the container after the mount.

Moreover, the rundeck:rundeck image at dockerhub seems to be updated almost daily, yet its faulty, when you attempt to pull that you're getting rundeck/rundeck:latest not found: manifest unknown.
Is it just me or is this project abandoned or just very raw?

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious why you think the project is abandoned? The repo at https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck is quite active.  We have releases every 3-4 weeks with release notes documented here: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/history/. These release notes cover fixes and enhancements to both our Open Source and Commercial products.

The Docker Hub is updated regularly due to the SnapShot builds that were mentioned previously.  We don't use the `latest` tag as upgrades should be a bit more methodically planned and using that tag can lead to unintended upgrades.

The issue with the volume mapping is likely due to setting that to read-only.  That folder will need to be written to for Rundeck to function correctly.

~Forrest

Answer (score 0):

The project is still alive, you can follow all changes [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pulls). Regarding the image tag you can use `SNAPSHOT` to get the last one, e.g: `rundeck/rundeck:SNAPSHOT` or just specify the latest stable version `rundeck/rundeck:4.3.1` at this moment.

You can see a lot of docker examples [here](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo), and regarding that directory, Rundeck needs to write on it.